# What is the equivalent concept of highstates with Ansible?

Tags: ansible, salt-stack

I'm use to Saltstack and I'm interessted now by Ansible.

But among all the questions I have, I didn't find anything regarding the Highstate (in Salt terminology). I use it to ensure my infrastructure is always at the desire state and to detect any anomaly if it's not.

What is the equivalent concept for that with Ansible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salt's states system is very similar to Ansible's approach.

Is Ansible's playbook suitable for you? You can define highstate.yml playbook and apply necessary changes.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking to create a top.yml including all the others playbook and run a "ansible-playbook top.yml" in cron task. But I want to be sure I don't miss an important functionality of Ansible.

Comment: The difference in supported features, but not in approach. I've read some books about both and can say that you will not make a mistake if choose one of them. You can implement some things by Salt, such as roles in Ansible, and vice versa. But for me it is more convinient to use Salt for Windows system, as its minion installer contains all your needs.